# Run running TCP and UDP server at the same time

Tags: java, networking, server, tcp, udp

I have a network programming topic that requires file transfer using TCP and UDP. If TCP send fails then UDP will be executed. I have built each part but I am not sure how can I run the server of TCP and UDP at the same time to be able to receive data of both protocols (my problem is starting 2 server in the master server because I have as the interface). Hope everybody help please .

Answer (score 0):

In one case you need to open a ServerSocket, in the other case a DatagramSocket. It should be possible to open them in parallel, which means you can run both your implementations in parallel running on different threads.

Comment: yes i use the same port but i cant run both threads parallel to each other i tried but only the first thread executes

Answer (score 0):

If you are suppose to run the TCP and the UDP Server on the same machine, you will need to use different ports. Then you can start up two different thread, one for each server:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class TcpUdpServer {

  private final static int UDP_PORT = 8100;
  private final static int TCP_PORT = 8200;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Thread(() -> executeTcpServer()).start();
    new Thread(() -> executeUdpServer()).start();
  }

  public static void executeTcpServer() {
    try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(TCP_PORT)) {
      while (true) {
        System.out.println("waiting for TCP connection...");
        // Blocks until a connection is made
        final Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
        final InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
        String text = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
            .lines()
            .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
        System.out.println(text);
      }
    } catch (Exception exception) {
      exception.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public static void executeUdpServer() {
    try (DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(UDP_PORT)) {
      while (true) {
        byte[] packetBuffer = new byte[2024];
        final DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(packetBuffer, packetBuffer.length);
        System.out.println("waiting for UDP packet...");
        // Blocks until a packet is received
        socket.receive(packet);
        final String receivedPacket = new String(packet.getData()).trim();
        System.out.println(receivedPacket);
      }
    } catch (Exception exception) {
      exception.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: If I write 2 threads like that, will it really run in parallel? Or process 1 has finished running, then process 2 will run

Comment: Yes, they will both run at concurrently, so the second thread will not wait on the first thread

Comment: Yes I have tried again successfully, but in case I want to multithread in both TCP and UDP, is there any way? I tried writing my own class to handle it, but when I put it on the server, only 1 TCP or UDP is executed

Comment: Can you share the code for that?

Comment: public class ServerUDP implements Runnable {
 DatagramSocket server;
 public ServerUDP(int port) {
  listen(port);
 }
 
 public void listen(int port) {
  try {
   System.out.println("ServerUDP: "+port);
   server=new DatagramSocket(port);
   while(true) {
    UDPThread UDPThread=new UDPThread(server);
    UDPThread.start();
   }
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }

 @Override
 public void run() {
  
  
 }

Comment: i dont understand i cant post code , TCP I also do the same, then on main server I create 2 new objects and put in 2 threads but it only executes 1 of 2

Comment: Not sure if I understand the code, so the Runnable `ServerUDP` invokes the listen method form the constructor. The `listen` method creates new `UDPThread` objects in an endless while-loop in a method, invoked from the constructor. If `UDPThread` extends `Thread`, it will create new Thread until the system resources are exhausted.